# Find relevant words according to a given subject

Tags: algorithm, web-services, search

Is there an algorithm, webservice or technique which is able to search through a list of words, returning these that fit a given subject?

**Practical example:**
There is a Software which allows me to create a task and select an icon for it. There are hundreds of icons, >95% of them do not fit the given task.

My idea now is to tag these icons:
An icon with a letter would get the tags `mail`, `communication`, `message`, ...

The user then adds a task which is called `Write email`. The algorithm searches the icons and their tags and returns a list of presumably fitting icons (Perhaps the 20 most fitting icons). The user then can select from this list.

I think this could be useful in different areas. In a time where google is able to predict what the user wants to search for it must be possible in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the greatest solution but giving it a shot.

If the terms in the input which would match against the icon is limited, consider a inverted index of terms against the icon label.

Say,

```
mail -> mailicon
email -> mailicon
```

On the similar line, hold a dictionary of a single term against icon label.

```
mail -> mailicon
message -> chaticon
communication ->lanicon
```

And when the terms "Write an email" comes from the user, you could explode the term as synonyms using something like a [SynExpand](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/wordnet/SynExpand.html) and look up the entire map for possible icons.

Say, email gets exploded into mail, message, communication etc. and you would get the suggestions as three icons.

I am sure you should be able to play with the synonym values based on your need.

Also refer to [Full Text Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053508/lucene-synonym-expansion-stemming-spell-check-and-more)